# How to get query for enum

Tags: mysql, sql, database, enums

So i have a table here and columns which is isAdmin and isTeacher

The datatype for isAdmin and isTeacher is enum(0,1).

```
id  Name    isAdmin    isTeacher

1   Admin      1          0

2  Teacher      0          1

3  Student     0          0
```

When i execute this query:

```
  SELECT * FROM users where isAdmin = 1 and isTeacher = 1
```

it gets me the

```
   Student **(assuming isAdmin = 0 and isTeacher =0)**
```

(I dont know why it shows that record o__o )

Now, i want to find the isTeacher,

I tried these queries...

```
  SELECT * FROM users where isAdmin = 1 and isTeacher = 1 and isAdmin = 0
```

(no results)

```
  SELECT * FROM users where isAdmin = 1 and isTeacher = 1 and isTeacher = 0
```

(no results)

```
  SELECT * FROM users where   isTeacher = 0 (it gets me the Admin and Student)
```

Please help? @_@

Comment: Why not try `Where isTeacher = 1` ? and you know at a time the column can not have both the value so this `isTeacher = 1 and isTeacher = 0` condition is disastar in any sense

Comment: I tried it and it only shows the isAdmin and Student :(

Comment: Can you indicate your expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using enum type you should use **string values** or **integer indecies**.

Assuming your (actual) field declarations are

```
...
isAdmin enum ('0','1'),
isTeacher enum ('0','1')
...
```

your query

```
SELECT * FROM users where isAdmin = 1 and isTeacher = 1
```

will return records with `isAdmin` field value equals '0' (value with index 1), same for `isTeacher`.

If you need to filter by value, not by index, you should use string value:

```
SELECT * FROM users where isAdmin = '1' and isTeacher = '1'
```

This query will return admins that are also teachers (your example data doesn't contain those).

N.B. 0th index identify NULL value.
For complete reference, see [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html).

Answer (score 0):

Are the three categories mutually exclusive?  If so, use

```
category ENUM('admin', 'teacher', 'student') NOT NULL
```

and test with

```
WHERE category = 'student'
```

(etc).  Simpler.  Clearer.